# Pasting multiple rows of data into single cell using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have combinations of names to tasks in a table where several different task are associated with the same name. But I need to put the task into one cell next to the associated name. Using JavaScript. Heres what I got;

```
   function Unique(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
      var dataRaw = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var destination = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      var names2 = dataRaw.getRange(2,10,dataRaw.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
      var names1 = names2.flat(1);
     
      
      
             var names = names1;
             //var names = ["name1","name1","name2", "name3", "name3"];
             var uniqueNames = []; //empty array
             var count = 0;
             var found = false;
      
      for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        for(y =0; y < uniqueNames.length; y++){
          if(names[i] == uniqueNames[y]){
                       found = true;
          }
        }    
        count++;
        if(count == 1 && found == false){
          uniqueNames.push(names[i]);
        }
        count = 0;
        found = false;
       }
    /*  can I use this??? maybe it's not needed
      var uniqueNames2 = uniqueNames.map(function(obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
        return obj[key];
      });
    });
     */

     var dest =  destination.getRange(1,2,uniqueNames.length,uniqueNames[0].length);
      
      dest.setValue(uniqueNames); //maybe this is not needed
      console.log(uniqueNames[0].length);
    }
```

My approach is to;

1. take in names and output the unique names so there is no doubles
2. once i have unique names use some type of `for() loop` or `map()` function to find tasks and pair with names? maybe im wrong?
3. and then `setValues()` to the range that I need.

The problems that I'm running into are that My `Unique()` function needs a regular array not array of arrays, which i fix using

```
    array.flat(1)
```

but then to paste the values javaScript needs the array or arrays to be just an array which I *COULD* fix with

```
    Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key)
```

in the commented out section? to turn an array of arrays back into an array... but then my "width" is not consistent for my array, columns, and I get the error that my range is not the same number of columns as my data. I feel that this is fairly simple and I am grossly over complicating things. Any help would be great thank you. My google sheet below https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rbz52kkzhVAGX21MUVoexzPUvWxjk-RCw-5PrRLoBBc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion.

  - From

    ```
      Task    Names
      Task 1  name one
      Task 2  name one
      Task 3  name one
      Task 4  name one
      Task 5  name one
      Task 1  name two
      Task 2  name two
      Task 3  name two
      Task 1  name three
      Task 2  name three
      Task 3  name three
    ```
  - To

    ```
      task    names
      Task 1
      Task 2
      Task 3
      Task 4
      Task 5  Name one
      Task 1
      Task 2
      Task 3  name two
      Task 1
      Task 2
      Task 3  name three
    ```

For this, how about this answer?

### Modification points:

- In your script, for example, about `var names2 = dataRaw.getRange(2,10,dataRaw.getLastRow(),1).getValues();`, I thought that you might misunderstand the row and column for `getRange`. And, in this case, only one row `Names` of column "B" on "Sheet1" is retrieved. The row of `Task` is not retrieved in your script. And also, from `dest.setValue(uniqueNames);`, you might misuderstood `setValue` and `setValues`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

In this modification, at `name2`, the values from the cells "B2:B12" are retrieved, and the unique values are retrieved using your script. Then, the values from the cells "A2:B12" are retrieved, and the values for putting to Spreadsheet are created using the created unique values. Then, the created values are put to the Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

```
function Unique_org2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var dataRaw = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var names2 = dataRaw.getRange(2,2,dataRaw.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues(); // <--- Modified
  var names1 = names2.flat(1);
  var names = names1;
  var uniqueNames = [];
  var count = 0;
  var found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    for(y =0; y < uniqueNames.length; y++){
      if(names[i] == uniqueNames[y]){
        found = true;
      }
    }    
    count++;
    if(count == 1 && found == false){
      uniqueNames.push(names[i]);
    }
    count = 0;
    found = false;
  }

  // --- I added below script.
  var values = dataRaw.getRange(2, 1, dataRaw.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues(); // Added
  var uniqueNames = uniqueNames.reduce((ar, e) => {
    var temp = "";
    values.forEach(([a, b]) => {
      if (e == b) temp += a + "\n";
    });
    ar.push([temp.trim(), e]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  // ---
  
  var dest =  destination.getRange(2,1,uniqueNames.length,uniqueNames[0].length);  // <--- Modified
  dest.setValues(uniqueNames);  // <--- Modified
}
```

### Other pattern:

In this pattern, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the other sample script of following flow. This flow might be able to reduce the process cost from above modified script.

1. Retrieve values from the cells "A2:B12" of "Sheet1".
2. Create an object from the retrieved values.
3. Convert the object to an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
4. Put the values to Spreadsheet to the destination sheet.

#### Sample script:

```
function Unique(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var dataRaw = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  
  // 1. Retrieve values from the cells "A2:B12" of "Sheet1".
  const values = dataRaw.getRange(2, 1, dataRaw.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an object from the retrieved values.
  const obj = values.reduce((o, [a, b]) => Object.assign(o, {[b]: (o[b] ? o[b] + a : a) + "\n"}), {});
  
  // 3. Convert the object to an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  const res = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [v.trim(), k]);
  
  // 4. Put the values to Spreadsheet to the destination sheet.
  destination.getRange(2, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: you answered my question exactly thank you! however, how would I modify the script so that it would also look at "name one's" data? as in; what id Name One had and address and zip code in the cell next to it? thank you

Comment: @Mauricio Alvarez Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new issue So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.